# Illegal start to expressions when called in another class (Java)

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors

I am trying to make a controller that will make a drone on a webpage move. When the main method (Robot) calls the controller (RobotMethods) it says all of my methods are illegal. I am sure that I am calling this correctly. I think I just need another set of eyes to look at it.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Robot
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not get the buttons to work. They are submitted with the assignment to see if I can solve this in the future.");
        System.out.println("Instead, please enter a command in the command line to move the robot.");
        System.out.println("The commands are: fly, land, climb, descend, strafel (strafe left), strafer (strafe right), turnl (turn left), turnr (turn right), forward, backwards.");
        System.out.println("Please enter commands exactly as written. All letters should be lower case!");
        new RobotFrame();
        RobotMethods robotMethods = new RobotMethods();

        Scanner pleaseWork = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = pleaseWork.nextLine();
        while (pleaseWork.hasNext())
        {
            switch(input)
            {
                case "fly":
                    robotMethods.Fly();
                    break;

                case "land":
                    robotMethods.Land();
                    break;

                case "climb":
                    robotMethods.Climb();
                    break;

                case "descend":
                    robotMethods.Descend();
                    break;

                case "strafel":
                    robotMethods.StrafeLeft();
                    break;

                case "strafer":
                    robotMethods.StrafeRight();
                    break;

                case "turnl":
                    robotMethods.TurnLeft();
                    break;

                case "turnr":
                    robotMethods.TurnRight();
                    break;

                case "forward":
                    robotMethods.Forward();
                    break;

                case "backwards":
                    robotMethods.Backwards();
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }   
}
```

Above is the main method, Robot.java Below is the RobotMethods.java

```
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
public class RobotMethods
{
    final String TAKEOFF_MESSSAGE = "{\"op\"publish\",\"topic\":\"/ardrone/takeoff\",\"msg\":{}}";
    final String LAND_MESSAGE = "{\"op\":\"publish\",\"topic\":\"/ardrone/land\",\"msg\":{}}";
    final String MOVE_BACKWARD_MESSAGE = "{\"receiver\":\"/cmd_vel\",\"msg\":{\"linear\":{\"x\":-0.25,\"y\":0,\"z\":0},\"angular\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}},\"type\":\"geometry_msgs/Twist\"}";
    final String MOVE_FORWARD_MESSAGE = "{\"receiver\":\"/cmd_vel\",\"msg\":{\"linear\":{\"x\":0.25,\"y\":0,\"z\":0},\"angular\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}},\"type\":\"geometry_msgs/Twist\"}";
    final String STRAFE_RIGHT_MESSAGE = "{\"receiver\":\"/cmd_vel\",\"msg\":{\"linear\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0.25,\"z\":0},\"angular\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}},\"type\":\"geometry_msgs/Twist\"}";
    final String STRAFE_LEFT_MESSAGE = "{\"receiver\":\"/cmd_vel\",\"msg\":{\"linear\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":-0.25,\"z\":0},\"angular\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}},\"type\":\"geometry_msgs/Twist\"}";
    final String TURN_RIGHT_MESSAGE = "{\"receiver\":\"/cmd_vel\",\"msg\":{\"linear\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0},\"angular\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":-0.25}},\"type\":\"geometry_msgs/Twist\"}";
    final String TURN_LEFT_MESSAGE = "{\"receiver\":\"/cmd_vel\",\"msg\":{\"linear\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0},\"angular\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0.25}},\"type\":\"geometry_msgs/Twist\"}";

    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter printer = null;

    RobotMethods()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket("private-lear.cs.okstate.edu", 9095);
            printer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR WHEN CREATING SOCKET!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public void makeSocket()
        {
            try
            {
                socket = new Socket("private-lear.cs.okstate.edu", 9095);
            printer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR WHEN CREATING SOCKET IN makeSocket!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        public String Fly()
        {
            printer.print(TAKEOFF_MESSSAGE);
            printer.flush();
        }

        public String Land()
        {
            printer.print(LAND_MESSAGE);
            printer.flush();
        }

        public String Climb()
        {
            System.out.println("To be added in the future.");
        }

        public String Descend()
        {
            System.out.println("To be added in the future.");
        }

        public String StrafeLeft()
        {
            printer.print(STRAFE_LEFT_MESSAGE);
            printer.flush();
        }

        public String StrafeRight()
        {
            printer.print(STRAFE_RIGHT_MESSAGE);
            printer.flush();
        }

        public String TurnLeft()
        {
            printer.print(TURN_LEFT_MESSAGE);
            printer.flush();
        }

        public String TurnRight()
        {
            printer.print(TURN_RIGHT_MESSAGE);
            printer.flush();
        }

        public String Forward()
        {
            printer.print(MOVE_FORWARD_MESSAGE);
            printer.flush();
        }

        public String Backwards()
        {
            printer.print(MOVE_BACKWARD_MESSAGE);
            printer.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

My Errors are

```
    .\RobotMethods.java:37: error: illegal start of expression
                public void makeSocket()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:37: error: illegal start of expression
                public void makeSocket()
                       ^
.\RobotMethods.java:37: error: ';' expected
                public void makeSocket()
                                      ^
.\RobotMethods.java:51: error: illegal start of expression
                public String Fly()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:51: error: ';' expected
                public String Fly()
                                 ^
.\RobotMethods.java:57: error: illegal start of expression
                public String Land()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:57: error: ';' expected
                public String Land()
                                  ^
.\RobotMethods.java:63: error: illegal start of expression
                public String Climb()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:63: error: ';' expected
                public String Climb()
                                   ^
.\RobotMethods.java:68: error: illegal start of expression
                public String Descend()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:68: error: ';' expected
                public String Descend()
                                     ^
.\RobotMethods.java:73: error: illegal start of expression
                public String StrafeLeft()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:73: error: ';' expected
                public String StrafeLeft()
                                        ^
.\RobotMethods.java:79: error: illegal start of expression
                public String StrafeRight()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:79: error: ';' expected
                public String StrafeRight()
                                         ^
.\RobotMethods.java:85: error: illegal start of expression
                public String TurnLeft()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:85: error: ';' expected
                public String TurnLeft()
                                      ^
.\RobotMethods.java:91: error: illegal start of expression
                public String TurnRight()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:91: error: ';' expected
                public String TurnRight()
                                       ^
.\RobotMethods.java:97: error: illegal start of expression
                public String Forward()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:97: error: ';' expected
                public String Forward()
                                     ^
.\RobotMethods.java:103: error: illegal start of expression
                public String Backwards()
                ^
.\RobotMethods.java:103: error: ';' expected
                public String Backwards()
                                       ^
Robot.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.Fly();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method Fly()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.Land();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method Land()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.Climb();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method Climb()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.Descend();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method Descend()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.StrafeLeft();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method StrafeLeft()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.StrafeRight();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method StrafeRight()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.TurnLeft();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method TurnLeft()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.TurnRight();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method TurnRight()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.Forward();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method Forward()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
Robot.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
                                        robotMethods.Backwards();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method Backwards()
  location: variable robotMethods of type RobotMethods
33 errors
```

Comment: You can't nest methods inside a constructor (or inside other methods).

Comment: Also, please read the java naming conventions, it looks like you are programming in C# or whatever. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: I can't believe I had a bracket in the wrong spot. Thank you so much. I will take another look at naming conventions, I am currently naming in accordance with my professor's standards but I could be wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Tell your professor that his standards for the Java language are wrong, show him the Oracle's documentations about it :)